# Finding the least in Count(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find all LID who have committed the least during a given time period. Following is my table:

```
| requestDate |    BID    |    LID    | PercentageContributed | DateComitted
| 1/10/2016   | S7444319C | S2262450A |           0.25        |   18/10/2016
| 1/10/2016   | S7444319C | S4495282I |           0.25        |   7/10/2016
| 1/10/2016   | S7444319C | S4792394D |           0.25        |   28/10/2016
| 1/10/2016   | S7444319C | S7173102K |           0.25        |   9/10/2016
| 25/10/2016  | S9981233W | S2848191X |           1.00        |   13/11/2016
| 28/10/2016  | S7611209X | S2848191X |           0.33        |   13/11/2016
| 28/10/2016  | S7611209X | S4792394D |           0.33        |   4/11/2016
| 28/10/2016  | S7611209X | S7145303Q |           0.33        |   5/11/2016
```

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT LID, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitte
FROM Commits
WHERE DateCommitted BETWEEN '2015-11-03' AND '2017-01-09'
GROUP BY LID
```

But I only managed to get the following:

```
|    LID    | TotalNumCommitte
| S2262450A |        1
| S2848191X |        2
| S4495282I |        1
| S4792394D |        2
| S7145303Q |        1
| S7173102K |        1
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
|    LID    | TotalNumCommitte
| S2262450A |        1
| S4495282I |        1
| S7145303Q |        1
| S7173102K |        1
```

I have also tried the following:

```
SELECT MIN(TotalNumCommitted)
FROM (
    SELECT LID, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitted
    FROM Commits
    WHERE DateCommitted >= '2015-11-03'
    AND DateCommitted <= '2017-01-09'
    GROUP BY LID
) T1
```

But I only get 1 (which is the minimum)
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you [edit] and add a tag for your database product (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a modern SQL with support for Common Table Expressions and ranking functions, something like this:

```
;WITH Counts as (
    SELECT LID, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitte
    FROM Commits
    WHERE DateCommitted BETWEEN '2015-11-03' AND '2017-01-09'
    GROUP BY LID
), RankedCounts as (
    SELECT *,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalNumCommitte) as rk
    FROM Counts
)
select *
from RankedCounts
where rk=1
```

Comment: You can do that with a single CTE using `rank() over (order by COUNT(*)) as rk` together with the `group by` query

Comment: It works. Thank you. But this way of doing seems new to me. Need to take some time understand. Anw @a_horse_with_no_name, what you mean by using single CTE?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES LID, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitte
FROM Commits
WHERE DateCommitted BETWEEN '2015-11-03' AND '2017-01-09'
GROUP BY LID
ORDER BY TotalNumCommitte;
```

Comment: Simple and sweet! Thank you so much it works. Never heard of TOP (1) WITH TIES LID until now

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL you'd use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` as in

```
SELECT LID, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitte
FROM Commits
WHERE DateCommitted BETWEEN '2015-11-03' AND '2017-01-09'
GROUP BY LID
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

In SQL Server you must use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` instead:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES LID, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitte
FROM Commits
WHERE DateCommitted BETWEEN '2015-11-03' AND '2017-01-09'
GROUP BY LID
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Comment: Does FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES only works in Oracle? I tried on SQL Server and is throwing me syntax error.

Comment: You had forgotten to specify your DBMS, so I posted the answer for Standard SQL. In SQL Server you'd use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yap I have realized that as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just looked it up: According to Wikipedia SQL Server features the `FETCH FIRST` clause as of version 2014, but demands an additional offset: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your group by query with a window function:

```
select lid, totalnumcommitte
from (
    select lid, 
           count(*) as totalnumcommitte, 
           rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
    from commits
    group by lid
) t
where rnk = 1
order by lid;
```

Or using a common table expression:

```
with counts as (
    select lid, 
           count(*) as totalnumcommitte, 
           rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
    from commits
    group by lid
)
select lid, totalnumcommitte
from counts
where rnk = 1
order by lid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LID, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitte FROM Commits WHERE DateCommitted BETWEEN '2015-11-03' AND '2017-01-09'
GROUP BY LID 
HAVING COUNT(*) =
(SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitted FROM Commits WHERE DateCommitted BETWEEN '2015-11-03' AND '2017-01-09'
GROUP BY LID ORDER BY TotalNumCommitted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the results of the aggregate function (count in this case), by using HAVING, for example:

```
SELECT LID, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumCommitte
FROM Commits
WHERE DateCommitted BETWEEN '2015-11-03' AND '2017-01-09'
GROUP BY LID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Two deleted answers so far - `1` is an *example* of the minimum from the data set. If the lowest result for any row is `2`, that's what would be wanted.